# DWR and other possible tools for build java application level Ajax framework

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I would assume that this question would have been asked in different ways already, but I could not find one so posting it. Sorry if its a repetition

The basic idea which I am trying to explore is to design a common Ajax framework/API for our application. The main requirement is to have a common framework in the product which every module in the application can call whenever it needs to provide Ajax behavior.

1. We basically have a page based application and not everything would be Ajax for sure. Mostly it will be smaller pieces of work which Ajax will handle.
2. We have used GWT and it works great. But we have some constraints because of which certain areas in the application need to build standard jsp and html pages only
3. I know little bit about dwr and it looks very promising (as even answered by some people).

I wanted to know what are the other possible frameworks like dwr which I can evaluate too, before making the decision

Comment: what exactly is the programming related question here?

Comment: Yes.. its not related to programming directly but programming choice. I was not sure which tags I should use

Answer (score 0):

This might help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ajax_frameworks#Java

But DWR works great. It is simple and very effective. I suggest you go for DWR.